# Parameterized sql queries with JDBC template

Tags: java, mysql, sql, spring, jdbc

I'm running into a problem where my parameterized queries with a single parameter will run fine, but when inserting more than one parameter, it doesn't work.

The following method works fine:

```
public Employee getEmployeeByID(int id) {
    String sql = "SELECT firstname, lastname FROM employees WHERE employeeID = ?";
    List<Employee> list = getEmployeeList(sql, id);
    if (list.isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    }
    return list.get(0);
}
```

Here is getEmployeeList, which it depends on:

```
private List<Employee> getEmployeeList(String sql, Object... params) {
    List<Employee> list = new ArrayList<Employee>();
    for (Object o : template.query(sql, mapper, params)) {
        list.add((Employee) o);
    }
    return list;
}
```

Note that `template` is an autowired JDBCTemplate, and `mapper` is an autowired RowMapper.

However, this method isn't working at all:

```
public List<Employee> getEmployeesBySearchCriteria(String criteria) {

    //business logic that determines the values
    //of Strings firstname, lastname, and keyword...

    String sql = "SELECT firstname, lastname FROM employees WHERE UPPER(firstname) LIKE UPPER('%?%') ? UPPER(lastname) LIKE UPPER('%?%')";

    return getEmployeeList(sql, firstname, keyword, lastname);

}
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (2 > number of parameters, which is 1).
```

I understand that I could just manually append each string into the sql statement, but I'm concerned about sql injection, and I can't figure out why this isn't working.  Is there a problem with my syntax?  Or am I going about this completely wrong?

Comment: You can't bind keywords in this way. You'll need to use string concatenation to do that bit.

Comment: @Laurence although that is a solution, it is an unacceptable solution due to the possibility of sql injection.  I am pretty sure there is a way for Spring to handle it for me, but I can't quite figure it out.

Comment: Not sure about this, but I remember having a problem like this. It's maybe linked to the `'%?%'` part. Try to use only the `?` and add the `%` to your string directly.

Comment: In purely SQL terms, you'd use a white list for keywords. I don't know if spring has some magic to make this easier in a cross-platform way.

Comment: You were right, @Jul13nT, it didn't like that part.  Appending it to my string parameters worked perfectly.  Go ahead and answer this question and I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `?` like that `'%?%'` in a like condition. You need to remove the `%` and append them to your string. For instance :

```
public List<Employee> getEmployeesBySearchCriteria(String criteria) {

    String sql = "SELECT firstname, lastname FROM employees WHERE UPPER(firstname) LIKE UPPER(?)";

    return getEmployeeList(sql, "%" + firstname + "%");

}
```